# Conditional formatting with relative reference in VBA not working on German Excel

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have this awkward issue:

I am adding the following conditional formatting with relative reference through VBA:

```
Activecell.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
                                Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=RC[-1]"
```

Although it is working fine on my machine with English Office 2010, it doesn't work on German Office 2010.

Do you know what might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try like this for the German people:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
        ActiveCell.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
                Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=ZS(-1)"    
End Sub
```

`RC` should be `ZS`.

`Z` is `Zeile`, `S` is `Spalte`.

Obviously the conditional formatting likes to support only local formulas.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it. What is really bizarre, is that if I use the record function, and type in to cell B1   =A1, the generated code is "=RC[-1]"  and not "=ZS[-1]".

Comment: @Thanasis - see the edit, the only change should be in the commas `)` and not `]`.

Comment: Perfect!! That change fixed it indeed! Thank you for the super fast response.